# Hungarian algorithm - Last step of selecting 0s from such that each row and column has only one selected

Tags: java, algorithm, hungarian-algorithm

I am trying to implement the Hungarian algorithm in Java. I have an NxN cost matrix. I am following [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-the-Hungarian-Algorithm) guide step by step and have reached step 9 -

> "Select a matching by choosing a set of zeros so that each row or
> column has only one selected."

I already have the matrix with the 0s.
I was trying to figure this out and the only thing that was working for me was a brute force method.

I also thought of choosing the first 0 I encounter, remove that column & row and repeat; But this method does not work.

Is there any trick or method? Something that's not too complex? Any suggestion would appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you managed to implement the algorithm downthere? Any questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer from a Hungarian: :)

- Calculate the number of `0` elements for each row and column. (call it `row[]` and `column[]`)
- Select the minimum **positive** value of the rows and columns. For example let it be `column[3]` (if the minimum value is found in a `row`, the same applies, only swap rows and columns) If you have more than one with the same value, select any.
- Select a `0` element in that column, mark it. If you have more than one, select any, that has a positive `row` value. (Suppose it is `row[1]`)
- Set `column[3]` to 0 (next time we shouldn't select). Also set `row[1]` to 0.
- Iterate in all elements in `column[3]`, if you find a `0` element, decrease the corresponding `row[i]` value by 1
- If you don't find a positive value in neither row or column, you are finished.

Comment: Actually the last 4 steps **can be made in one loop**, if you always select the first `0` element in the columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped. I apologize for the delay.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for the matrix `[[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0]]`. It gives the following assignment: `(0; 0), (1; 0), (2; 1)`, where it should be `(0; 2), (1; 0), (2; 1)`.

Comment: @Nicolas You are correct, one step is missing: when you mark a row/column pair, the corresponding `row` and `column` values both must be set to `0`. Fixing it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I changed it but I found it also fails with `[[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]]`, giving `0-1, 1-0, 2-1` instead of `0-1, 1-0, 2-2`. The problem seems to be at step 3, because since there are 2 zeroes in the last row, it selects any, so the first one, which is in an already assigned row. I changed it to "Select any zero in that column and only in rows with positive values." (and vice versa if the minimum value was a row). I tested it for several matrices and it seems to work fine.

Comment: However I still feel like this method isn't optimal. I've looked at a few example implementations and none of them seem to be doing it this way (or Wikipedia's way for that matter). I think that [the method described here](http://csclab.murraystate.edu/~bob.pilgrim/445/munkres.html) may lead to a cleaner implementation than what Wikipedia suggests. The assignment is given directly as a result of the algorithm, as opposed to your method which required over 70 lines for me.

Comment: @Nicolas yes, that's the second issue, we should npt only mark it as forbidden, but that mark must be enforced, too, So, any `0` element that is selected must have a positive row-column value.

Comment: Regarding complexity: The Hungarian algorithm is not my expertise, I didn't have to implement it myself. The task is not trivial though, otherwise it wouldn't be asked here, I digged into the topic as it was an interesting one.
There are two options: you can solve it with a backtrack (like "8 queens problem"), or implement a specific algo (because it can be sorted in one pass)

Comment: The logic behind this algorithm is that those rows/cols that have abundant number of `0`s should remain at last, and those that have just a few should be picked first, This was measured by the rows/cols arrays (actually that can be represented by one single array of size 2N, an index there can represent a row-or-column) This bit of indexing trick might save you a number of `if` statement.